# ASP.NET MVC and Web Forms registration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

How does IIS know when to route a requests to the ASP.NET MVC framework and the not the Web Forms framework?

Looking through the Web.config of an MVC project I can't see any modules or handlers that are registered, and nothing the Global.ascx seems to do it. So I am at a bit of a loss as to how the system decides which should be used to route a request.

Comment: Hint: MapRoute(). Another Hint: Place a breakpoint in any action method and look at the call stack. (make sure to enable framework source stepping in options)

Comment: MVC doesn't serve the view file directly, so you can't request a view, your request has to come through a action method, which will then return the desired view.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the MapRoute method the system registers a set of Routes which offload a matching request to an IRouteHandler. The IRouteHandler then returns a IHttpHandler that actually handles the final request.

This is my understanding so far so it might not be 100% correct.